# Risk of routing malicious email through internal email infrastructure

Tags: email

This has been a long standing question of mine and I haven't been able to find a satisfactory answer so I hope someone here can help me out.

My question is - Imagine there is an email being routed out to the internet using an organization's internal email infrastructure (Microsoft Exchange, etc). If this email has a malicious attachment or a malicious script embedded in the email body, then I presume the risk of compromise is only to the recipient and not to the email infrastructure itself?

Discussions with colleagues always result in them saying we need to assume there is a risk to the email infrastructure but no one seems to be able to articulate what the risk is and how a compromise of the email infrastructure is possible.

Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 4):

This depends if the mail is only routed (i.e. simple MTA) or if any kind of deeper analysis will be done (firewalls, IPS, BDS...). In the first case there is probably not much of an risk. But in the last case it is possible that the malware will be extracted and analyzed by some middleware. Such analysis is a complex issue and often contain bugs. In the worst case the analysis system itself could be compromised this way.

This is not a hypothetical attack. Such attacks happened against [FireEye BDS](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2015/12/fireeye-exploitation-project-zeros.html) where the passive monitoring of the traffic done by the BDS could be turned into an exploit. And another such issue existed with [Symantec Endpoint Protection](http://googleprojectzero.blogspot.de/2016/06/how-to-compromise-enterprise-endpoint.html) including Symantec Email Security. And probably others are affected too.

Answer (score 3):

This topic is of cause highly hypthetical but whenever you have a system attached to te internet that is processing data from clients there is the risk of a vulnerablity in the code that is used to process this data.

When it comes to E-Mail infrastructure this vulnerblity mitght be in a part of the serverside software or in the anti spam/virus solutions. This is especially critical becaus this software has almost in every case at least administrative if not system privileges. There was actually a [vulnerablity in symantecs AV/Antispam solutions](http://www.securityweek.com/critical-vulnerability-symantec-av-engine-can-be-exploited-sending-email) that could be triggered by just sending a mail. If you have such a solution installed on your mailserver it might be infected by just passing a mail through while scanning it.

Answer (score 1):

Modern "mail infrastructure" performs much more tasks than simply relaying passive data thus might become a target for attacker itself.

Particularly, it:

- stores the data, often in complex structures
- indexes the data
- inspects the data
- trigger automated rules based on the data

These actions imply data processing and in effect open a possibility to exploit the system.

Given the functions of these systems are well-defined and limited in comparison to a PC, and given the lack of user interaction, the chances for a breach are small but not zero.

While most of it should be a concern for developers, the notion of the risk to the email infrastructure, i.e. that the mall server itself might get compromised, should encourage administrative to implement security practices like server isolation and proper monitoring.

---

Dealing with uncertainty is a part of security and for example if you look at the description of one of Microsoft Exchange vulnerabilities ([CVE-2013-0418](https://www.cvedetails.com/cve/CVE-2013-0418/)) it doesn't require to be "specified" and "known" to be considered a threat:

> **Unspecified vulnerability** in the Oracle Outside In Technology component in Oracle Fusion Middleware 8.3.7 and 8.4 allows context-dependent attackers to affect availability **via unknown vectors** related to (...)